# Python2.5 Popen object with no PID

Tags: python, popen, monkeyrunner, python-2.5

I am trying to launch and then stop an Android emulator from a python 2.5 script (to be executed with `monkeyrunner`), and I wrote the following code:

```py
def launchDevice(avd_name, wipe=False):
    cmd = ['~/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd %s' % avd_name]
    if wipe:
        cmd.append(' -wipe-data')

    print 'Starting the emulator %s...' % avd_name
    emulator = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=-1)
    return emulator

#end

def main():
    # launch the emulator
    emulator_proc = launchDevice('Nexus5')
    print emulator_proc.pid
    # stop the emulator
    os.kill(emulator_proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)

#end

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute this script I get a working Android emulator (so the `subprocess.Popen` instruction works), but then I get an error (`TypeError: kill(): 1st arg can't be coerced to int`) in `os.kill` function since the `emulator_proc`'s PID is `None` (verified by the output message).

How is it possible to have a `None` PID?

Comment: Puzzling...  it shouldn't be None. The `Popen` constructor initializes it to `None` but by the time `__init__` is done, its set to the child pid. All failures in `__init__` raise an exception but in that case, `emulator_proc` would not have been assigned.

Comment: Is this the whole code? If not, maybe some other component is inadvertently resetting `emulator_proc.pid` to None. Studying the [2.5 version of `subprocess.Popen`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.5/Lib/subprocess.py) doesn't reveal an obvious way for process launch to succeed with the `pid` field remaining None - the line `self.pid = os.fork()` ties the success of forking to storing the PID.

Comment: Yes, that's all the code (the only part missing are the `import`s). By the way I executed that code inside a python shell and discovered that it works; so I inspected the `monkeyrunner` script and found that actually it is a Java program that exploits Jython, so probably the problem is a bug in Jython's implementation of Popen or something like that